ESP32 Matter - TEST_SETUP_PARAMS disabling error
When I tried to build ESP32 light example with production setup, I turned off the ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS option along with their guide.
But the build was failed with no definition of ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS.
How can I solve this ?
    ../../../../../esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/platform/ESP32/CHIPDevicePlatformConfig.h:127:53: error: "CONFIG_ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
  127 | #define CHIP_DEVICE_CONFIG_ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS CONFIG_ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../esp-matter/connectedhomeip/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/include/platform/CHIPDeviceConfig.h:1214:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CHIP_DEVICE_CONFIG_ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS'
 1214 | #if CHIP_DEVICE_CONFIG_ENABLE_TEST_SETUP_PARAMS
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option '-Wno-unknown-warning-option' may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
[184/347] c++ obj/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/protocols/echo/libChipProtocols.EchoServer.cpp.o
[185/347] c++ obj/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/protocols/echo/libChipProtocols.EchoClient.cpp.o
[186/347] c++ obj/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/protocols/secure_channel/libChipProtocols.MessageCounterManager.cpp.o
[187/347] c++ obj/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/protocols/user_directed_commissioning/libChipProtocols.UserDirectedCommissioningClient.cpp.o
[188/347] c++ obj/third_party/connectedhomeip/src/protocols/user_directed_commissioning/libChipProtocols.UserDirectedCommissioningServer.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

 *  The terminal process "ninja" terminated with exit code: 1. 

enter image description here
